# Why is it corny to say "I'm sweet enough"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Here is a dialog from [Snatch, the movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snatch_%28film%29)

> - You take sugar?
> - No thank you, Turkish; I'm sweet enough

I like to use it but an Irishman told me the other day that it was a corny thing to say "I'm sweet enough" and I'm wondering why. He said it wasn't gay, just corny.

If it's meaningless to ask why something is considered daft or dated, then how corny is it to use this, on a scale from 1 to 10?

Comment: From the reference to "gay", I'm going to assume you and the person you were talking to are male. Call me sexist if you must, but it's a question of delivery - an adult male saying something like that is likely to be corny, while a female or a young boy saying it could be a combination of cute and sassy.

Comment: Hi V-R, this question is off-topic for our site, because it is entirely a matter of opinion, like, for example, *Do these pants make me look gay?*

Comment: Yes T.J.L., I'm a straight male and so is my Irish friend. Sweet enough was a joke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corny:"Something presented as fresh or original, but which is actually tired and/or lame." I have not heard the expression "I'm sweet enough" for about 50 years and even then it was old-fashioned. 'on a scale of 1 to 10': Is 1 slightly corny and 10 extremely corny? If so I mark it as 10.